# How to block an inaccessible hole in a masonry wall?

Tags: masonry, cement, mortar

I have vermin getting in, we believe through a hole gnawed in the mortar between an old brick wall and a newer blockwork wall. Ordinarily it would just be a matter of sealing up that at the exterior, with cement, fresh mortar, whatever.

However the hole is very difficult to reach. It's at the end of a 3 meter long triangular gap between solid exterior walls. The open end of the triangle is 20cm wide, and the gap narrows as we go back. Opposite that opening, 3 meters away, the walls join, and that's where the hole is.

There is a roof over this gap, so dropping wet cement from above isn't practical.

[image]

How could I block this hole?

Things I've considered:

- constructing a chute (from drainpipe?) and rolling a wet mix (of what?) in

  - I don't know what flows freely enough for this to work
- using some form of chute to get a dry product to the area, and rely on atmospheric moisture to set it

  - Again I don't know enough about how dry cement etc. pours
- pump cement down a hose (a professional job?)
- throw/fling it?
- blow dry cement in somehow?
- ram wire wool into the corner with a long pole and hope that's enough?
- roll in a ball of some kind of putty, then push it into the space with a pole?

Visual appearance isn't important, I don't mind a mound of cement in that corner.

Comment: Concrete will run down a chute at about a 45 degree angle.  Can make a push stick with the shape of the chute at the end.  Concrete is heavy so depending how deep you need(a couple feet) it might push on the walls a bit, a few inches should be okay.

Comment: How are they getting to the hole in the first place? There's always going to be an exterior-most entry point.

Comment: @KMJ This triangle is the exterior. The inside of the hole - we surmise - is below a suspended floor that would be quite a lot of effort and expense to disturb. I'll clarify it in the question.

Comment: Maybe high density expanding foam pumped in from a truck?   Depending on what vermin you're dealing with this may or may not be effective.  But it seems like a liquid sprayed in by a long wand that could reach the far corner would be a good solution to the accessibility problem.

Comment: Any chance you can access the location from inside the house?  Otherwise, jerry rig up a spray foam can extender and see if you can reach that way.  Might be able to duct tape a can on the end of a pole with another rod screwed to the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Work around the access issue, and patch the hole some other way. Either put a patch/barrier on the inside of of your building, or build a wall to cover the opening of the triangle to prevent access to the space entirely.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually going to brick up the front of the triangle, but I'm worried if I don't deal with the hole, something will burrow in though the ground and find its way in -- and the access point be even more inaccessible to humans

Comment: If you wanted to go this way you could get some pumped cement put in on the ground between the buildings before you put in the wall. Seems like a lot of work though.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to block pests is to put steel or copper wool inside of expanding foam. I think you could do the same thing in this circumstance with some preparation. Long endoscope cameras have gotten inexpensive. You would need a long fiberglass or aluminum pole with a camera taped a bit back from the end. First you could use it to inspect the hole, then to stuff some metal wool in there, then to fill it with expanding foam through a long tube.